# Referring constants in a different Xcode target between ObjC and Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have two targets in a Xcode project:

1. Objective-C app target
2. Swift UI automation target

And I have many global constants with accessibility IDs in a header file in the app target that I want to use in the automation code, e.g. the header file contains:

```
static NSString *const APP_TUTORIAL_VIEW_ACI = @"tutorial_view";
static NSString *const APP_TUTORIAL_SCROLL_VIEW_ACI = @"tutorial_scroll_view";
```

but if I try to access for example `APP_TUTORIAL_VIEW_ACI` in the automation Swift code it can't find it.

How do I link this so that the global constants can be used in the Swift automation target?

Comment: Have you imported Objective-C header file where constants are, in your project's bridging header file?

Comment: There is actually no bridging header file in the Swift target. Xcode didn't create one. Do you know how/where I should create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create Objective-C Bridging Header file in your Objective-C target by adding a temp swift file. The Xcode will prompt you to add  Objective-C bridger header file. The name of the bridging header would be

> [YourTargetName]-Bridging-Header.h

[image]

2. Add your constants file in ths bridging header:

   `#import "ConstantsHeader.h"`
3. Go to build settings of your Objective-C target. Search for "bridging" and copy the value from SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER

[image]

4. Go to build settings of your Swift Test Target. Again search for "bridging" and paste the copied value in Objective-C Bridging Header

[image]

5. You can use the constant directly now in Swift Test Target.

   > ```
   > func testExample() {
   >         let str = APP_TUTORIAL_VIEW_ACI
   >         XCTAssert(!str.isEmpty, "str should not be empty")
   >         XCTAssert(str == "tutorial_view", "str should match")
   >         // This is an example of a functional test case.
   >         // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.
   >     }
   > ```

Comment: Thanks alot but now I get an error when try to compile the Swift target: `Error:(14, 8) unknown type name 'NSString' Included from: Foo-Bridging-Header.h`. Also, in the bridging header I had to use C-style import : #import ...

Comment: Yeah it was meant to be #import, markdown somehow skipped it.I have fixed it and edited the answer. You should not have got the error in your Swift file though. If you can share your project, i would be glad to help.

Comment: Figured it out! I also had to put `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` into the bridging header file. Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: Glad to help. Cheers!